# How to show which records are being viewed in aspnet gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm sure this is really basic but I can't understand how its done...

On a lot of systems I've seen at my last job and that friends have shown me, I see they add in a note with each gridview that says `Showing x to y of z records`

So for example, if I have a gridview that shows 15 rows and my total datatable has 89 rows in it and I'm on the 1st page, what I want to show the user is `Showing 1 to 15 of 89 records`

Now, obviously I can get the total record count from DataTable.Rows.Count, but how do I determine which exact records the user is viewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    int currentPage = (MyGridView.PageIndex + 1);
    int firstRowNumber = ((currentPage * MyGridView.PageSize) - MyGridView.PageSize)+1;
    int lastRowNumber = (firstRowNumber + MyGridView.Rows.Count)-1;

    MyLabel.Text = string.Format("Page: {0} of {1}, Showing rows {2} to {3} of {4}", currentPage, MyGridView.PageCount, firstRowNumber, lastRowNumber, MyDataTable.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine which row user is viewing then you should change the page size in the gridview

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: as per your question you want to know what row user is viewing so you can set the page size minimum 3 or 5 so that the user has less choices